# Updating data from realtime database through Firebase Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a user point system for my app using Firebase and I'm currently handling the back end part of my project. I want to update the user points on a daily/monthly basis through firebase functions and right now I'm figuring out how to update the points.

I've tried using the code below but nothing really changes in my database.

[image: Realtime Database Image]

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp;

export const onPointsEdit = functions.database
.ref('/Users/{userId}/points')
.onWrite((change, context)=>{
    // Only edit data when it is first created.
    if (change.before.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Exit when the data is deleted.
    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const original = change.after.val();
    console.log('PointsChanging', context.params.pushId, original)
    const newPoints = parseInt(original)/100*10 + parseInt(original)
    const newPoint = newPoints.toString

    return change.after.ref.set(newPoint);
})
```

Comment: How do you trigger this function right now?

Comment: running firebase deploy in the terminal

Comment: i think its triggered when i change the database, is there a way for me to change it directly without making any changes in the database? As i want it to be updated automatically daily.

Comment: Running `firebase deploy` doesn't trigger a function. The function you declared is triggered by a change in the value at `/Users/{userId}/points`. If you instead want to run this periodically have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions. If you want to call it directly, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events